# How to make a fixed region hold a larger region in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Apologies for the word salad in the title (I'm just not sure how to describe it). What I'm looking for is to define a set region (say a UIView) that can hold a "larger" region inside of it. Users can explore this larger region by dragging with their finger (essentially just moving across this region).

Basically, I'm looking for a sort of google maps like UI (except I don't necessarily want zooming) for some fixed set region. I have a huge series of buttons that I can't possibly fit on the screen and would like to fit this into this dynamic view. Does anyone have any resources to point me to on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option here is to implement bigger view and then put in into UIScrollView

The second option is to use CAScrollLayer, but in this case you won't be able to handle touches

Comment: I looked up UIScrollView and it looks like I can only scroll up and down with it. This maybe a good first step, but I was looking more free movement (like going left and right as well?)

Comment: it is scrollable in any direction

Comment: I've done the same thing you described using UIScroll view

Comment: Thanks! One quick question, how do I add a solid border around a UIScrollView? I tried: test.layer.masksToBounds = true
        test.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        test.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 10/255, green: 10/255, blue: 10/255, alpha: 1.0 ).cgColor
        test.layer.borderWidth = 7.0 where test is a UIScrollView and I'm not getting anything.